# Conditional statement not working - arrays

Tags: javascript

I have this (novice) JS question:

I have this simple function *function movieStorage()*, which I want to check if the Yes button is clicked - if so it should storage the output (RandomItem in a new array (movieSaver).

the Output is a random value from the hMovies-array - generated when the Yes button is clicked.

```js
var hMovies = [
  "hMovie1",
  "hMovie18"
];

var movieSaver = [];

var randomItem = hMovies[Math.floor(Math.random() * hMovies.length)];

document.getElementById("buttonYes").addEventListener("click", ifClickedYes);

function ifClickedYes() {
  document.getElementById("showResult").innerHTML = randomItem;
  return (true);
}

function movieStorage() {
  if (ifClickedYes()) {
    movieSaver.push(randomItem);
  }
}
console.log(movieSaver);
```

```html
<button id="buttonYes">Yes</button>
<div id="showResult"></div>
```

Comment: So what's the problem? Your `ifClickedYes` sets inner HTML of `#showResult` and returns `true` without any conditions.

Comment: "return true" without parenthesis

Comment: From where is **movieStorage()** called?

Comment: When did you invoke `movieStorage()` ?

Comment: @VictorPopescu - although it looks incorrect there is no issue with `return(true);`

Comment: Do you have any errors in your developer tool console (press F12 in your browser)?

Comment: And also, what's the actual question? Is there any error in the console.?

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please update it with relevant HTML and explain what the problem is

Comment: Sorry to be unclear! 
My problem is when I click the button - the movieSaver remains the same (empty array) - but I wanted it to take the value I´ve got from randomItem (output from (ifClickedYes), and add it to the movieSaver array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no point to check the condition which will be always `true`. You do not need the second function. The only thing you need is to push the elements to array in the function attached to `onclick` event.

Also, use generate a new random index on click every time.

```
var hMovies = [
   "hMovie1",
   "hMovie18"];

var movieSaver = [];
document.getElementById("buttonYes").addEventListener("click", ifClickedYes);

function ifClickedYes(){
  var randomItem = hMovies[Math.floor(Math.random()*hMovies.length)];
  movieSaver.push(randomItem)
  document.getElementById("showResult").innerHTML = randomItem;
  console.log(movieSaver);
}
```

#### Working Snippet:

```js
var hMovies = [
   "hMovie1",
   "hMovie18"];

var movieSaver = [];
document.getElementById("buttonYes").addEventListener("click", ifClickedYes);

function ifClickedYes(){
  var randomItem = hMovies[Math.floor(Math.random()*hMovies.length)];
  movieSaver.push(randomItem)
  document.getElementById("showResult").innerHTML = randomItem;
  console.log(movieSaver);
}
```

```html
<button id="buttonYes">Yes</button>
<div id="showResult"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It was excatly what I needed. it works now :D